# Spark Streaming Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to read from a Kafka topic that has been set up by another team.  The topic is balanced across multiple partitions.  By this i mean that every new line is sent to a separate topic.  One message is multiple lines, so the message is split between the two partitions.

ex:
partition 1:
"message1: details1 details1"
"message2: details2 details2"

partition 2:
"details1 details1"
"details2 details2"

When I read the topic with `createDirectStream(ssc, kafkaparams, fromoffsets, messagehandler)`, I get the RDDs in the order shown above.

What I would like to do is:

"message1: details1 details1"
"details1 details1"
"message2: details2 details2"
"details2 details2"

Thanks for any help I receive.

Comment: what is the question ? what is the issue and what have you tried ?

Comment: Can't do it easily -- and not with your data. They need to be in the same partition, otherwise there is no guarantee on ordering, or that you will see them even in the same `RDD` within your `foreachRDD`. The only way you could do it in theory would be to have a seqID or something that you can use to re-order the records after they have been sent out of order. But you don't appear to have any such data.

Comment: Sorry, the question is how can I process multiple partitions in a topic in order.  When I read the data in with createStream or createDirectStream, it does not come in in the order it was added to kafka.  How can I pull from the partitions in the order they were added?  I have tried the two stream commands, but I have had trouble finding relevant information about spark streaming from Kafka.

Comment: @DavidGriffin Thanks for the reply.  That is unfortunate... I will have to reach out to the team that is sending the data to kafka.

Answer (score 0):

If the ordering inside each partitions is guaranteed so that element x in partition 1 relates to element x in partition 2, you could order the RDD element based on the partition number and the element index inside each partition iterator (zipWithIndex).

This would allow you to "re-sync" across partitions